My WebRTC has stopped sending audio to the peers when video is toggled to off
The code is attached below. Audio working absolutely fine on screen sharing and when the video is on. But as I turn off the video, my audio stops going to my peers though I can hear them well. I dont know what's causing the issue. I have really tried a lot. Any help from senior developer will be much appreciated.
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import { cloneDeep } from "lodash";
  import "./VideoCallComp.css";
  import { useSocketContext } from "../../Context/SocketContext";
  import usePlayer from "../../Hooks/usePlayer";
  import VideoPlayerComp from "../../Components/VideoCall/VideoPlayerComp/VideoPlayerComp";
  import CopySection from "../../Components/VideoCall/CopySection/CopySection";
  import Bottom from "../../Components/VideoCall/Bottom/BottomVideoCall";
  import usePeer from "../../Hooks/usePeer";
  import useMediaStream from "../../Hooks/useMediaStream";
  import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
  import { Row, Col } from "antd";
  import { Pin, PinOff, ScreenShare, ScreenShareOff } from "lucide-react";
  import { CallTimer } from "../../Components/VideoCall/CallTimer/CallTimer";
  import ScreenRecording from "../../Components/VideoCall/ScreenRecorder/ScreenRecorder";
  import { isAuthenticated } from "../../Components/Auth/auth";
  
  const VideoCallComp = () => {
      const router = useNavigate();
      const location = useLocation();
      const socket = useSocketContext();
      const [screenShare, setScreenShare] = useState(false);
      const [pinnedUser, setPinnedUser] = useState("");
      const [refreshPeer, setRefreshPeer] = useState(false);
      const roomId = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("roomID");
      const { peer, myId } = usePeer(refreshPeer);
      const { stream } = useMediaStream(screenShare);
      const {
          players,
          setPlayers,
          nonHighlightedPlayers,
          toggleAudio,
          toggleVideo,
          leaveRoom
      } = usePlayer(myId, roomId, peer);
  
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  
      console.log("video off stream", stream?.getTracks());
  
      // Function to update all streams with the new stream
      const updateAllStreams = (newStream) => {
          if (!newStream || !peer || !myId) return;
          Object.keys(users).forEach(userId => {
              const call = users[userId];
              if (call) {
                  call?.peerConnection?.getSenders()?.forEach(sender => {
                      if (sender.track.kind === 'video') {
                          sender.replaceTrack(newStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
                      } else if (sender.track.kind === 'audio') {
                          sender.replaceTrack(newStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
                      }
                  });              }
          });
      };
  
  
  
      useEffect(() => {
          if (!socket || !peer || !stream) return;
  
          const handleUserConnected = (newUser) => {
              console.log(`user connected in room with userId ${newUser}`);
              callUser(newUser?.userId, stream, newUser?.loggedInUser);
          };
  
          const callUser = (userId, stream, loggedInUser) => {
              const call = peer.call(userId, stream, loggedInUser);
  
              call.on("stream", (incomingStream) => {
                  console.log("incomingStream", incomingStream)
                  setPlayers((prev) => ({
                      ...prev,
                      [userId]: {
                          url: incomingStream,
                          loggedInUser,
                          muted: false,
                          playing: true,
                      },
                  }));
                  console.log("callObject", call);
                  setUsers((prev) => ({
                      ...prev,
                      [userId]: call,
                  }));
              });
          };
  
          socket.on("user-connected", handleUserConnected);
  
          return () => {
              socket.off("user-connected", handleUserConnected);
          };
      }, [peer, setPlayers, socket, stream, users]);
  
      useEffect(() => {
          if (!socket) return;
          const handleToggleAudio = (userId) => {
              console.log(`user with id ${userId} toggled audio`);
              setPlayers((prev) => {
                  const copy = cloneDeep(prev);
                  copy[userId].muted = !copy[userId].muted;
                  return { ...copy };
              });
          };
  
          const handleToggleVideo = (userId) => {
              console.log(`user with id ${userId} toggled video`);
              setPlayers((prev) => {
                  const copy = cloneDeep(prev);
                  copy[userId].playing = !copy[userId].playing;
                  // copy[userId].muted = false;
                  return { ...copy };
              });
          };
  
          const handleUserLeave = (userId) => {
              console.log(`user ${userId} is leaving the room`);
              users[userId]?.close();
              const playersCopy = cloneDeep(players);
              delete playersCopy[userId];
              setPlayers(playersCopy);
          };
  
          socket.on("user-toggle-audio", handleToggleAudio);
          socket.on("user-toggle-video", handleToggleVideo);
          socket.on("user-leave", handleUserLeave);
          return () => {
              socket.off("user-toggle-audio", handleToggleAudio);
              socket.off("user-toggle-video", handleToggleVideo);
              socket.off("user-leave", handleUserLeave);
          };
      }, [players, setPlayers, socket, users]);
  
      // console.log("coming stream", stream);
  
      useEffect(() => {
          if (!peer || !stream) return;
          peer.on("call", (call) => {
              const { peer: callerId } = call;
              call.answer(stream);
  
              call.on("stream", (incomingStream) => {
                  console.log("incomingStream", incomingStream)
                  console.log(`incoming stream from ${callerId}`);
                  setPlayers((prev) => ({
                      ...prev,
                      [callerId]: {
                          url: incomingStream,
                          muted: false,
                          playing: true,
                      },
                  }));
  
                  setUsers((prev) => ({
                      ...prev,
                      [callerId]: call,
                  }));
              });
          });
      }, [peer, setPlayers, stream]);
  
      useEffect(() => {
          if (!stream || !myId) return;
          console.log(`setting my stream ${myId}`);
          let loggedInUser = {
              email: isAuthenticated()?.email,
              fullName: isAuthenticated()?.fullName
          }
          setPlayers((prev) => ({
              ...prev,
              [myId]: {
                  url: stream,
                  loggedInUser,
                  muted: false,
                  playing: true,
              },
          }));
  
          updateAllStreams(stream); // Update streams for all peers in real-time
      }, [myId, setPlayers, stream, screenShare]);
  
      // Set the default pinned user
      useEffect(() => {
          if (!pinnedUser && Object.keys(nonHighlightedPlayers).length > 0) {
              const firstNonHighlightedPlayerId = Object.keys(nonHighlightedPlayers)[0];
              const firstNonHighlightedPlayer = {
                  playerId: firstNonHighlightedPlayerId,
                  ...nonHighlightedPlayers[firstNonHighlightedPlayerId]
              };
              setPinnedUser(firstNonHighlightedPlayer);
          }
      }, [nonHighlightedPlayers, pinnedUser]);
  
      const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          // Included for legacy support, e.g. Chrome/Edge < 119
          event.returnValue = true;
          leaveRoom();
          socket.disconnect();
      };
  
      const handleUnload = () => {
          if (socket && roomId && myId) {
              leaveRoom();
              socket.disconnect();
              document.location.reload();
          }
      };
  
      useEffect(() => {
          window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
          window.addEventListener("unload", handleUnload);
  
          return () => {
              window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
              window.removeEventListener("unload", handleUnload);
          };
      }, [socket, roomId, myId, players]);
  
      const handleLeaveRoom = () => {
          leaveRoom();
          router("/");
          setTimeout(() => {
              document.location.reload();
          }, 1200);
      }
  
      const handleToggleVideOnScreenShare = (val) => {
          setScreenShare(val);
          setTimeout(() => {
              toggleVideo();
              toggleVideo();
          }, 1500);
      }
  
      return (
          <div className="videoCallPage">
              <CallTimer />
              {
                  isAuthenticated()?.role === 1 &&
                  <ScreenRecording roomId={roomId} />
              }
              <Row className="videos mt-3">
                  <Col xs={24} md={24} className="inActivePlayerContainer">
                      {Object.keys(nonHighlightedPlayers).map((playerId, index) => {
                          const { url, muted, playing, loggedInUser } = nonHighlightedPlayers[playerId];
                          let makePinnedUser = nonHighlightedPlayers[playerId];
                          makePinnedUser.playerId = playerId;
                          return (
                              url?.active &&
                              <div key={index} className={pinnedUser?.playerId === playerId ? "VideoPlayerSection pinnedVideo" : "VideoPlayerSection otherVideos"}>
                                  <div>
                                      {pinnedUser?.playerId === playerId ? (
                                          <PinOff className="text-white pinIcon" onClick={() => setPinnedUser("")} />
                                      ) : (
                                          <Pin className="text-white pinIcon" onClick={() => setPinnedUser(makePinnedUser)} />
                                      )}
                                      <VideoPlayerComp
                                          key={playerId}
                                          url={url}
                                          muted={playerId === myId || muted}
                                          playing={playing}
                                          toggleAudio={toggleAudio}
                                          isActive={false}
                                      />
                                      {
                                          // myId === playerId &&
                                          (
                                              <Bottom
                                                  myId={myId}
                                                  playerId={playerId}
                                                  loggedInUser={loggedInUser}
                                                  muted={muted}
                                                  playing={playing}
                                                  toggleAudio={toggleAudio}
                                                  toggleVideo={toggleVideo}
                                                  leaveRoom={handleLeaveRoom}
                                              />
                                          )}
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          );
                      })}
                  </Col>
              </Row>
              {
                  // isAuthenticated()?.role === 1 &&
                  <button className="screensharebtn btn">
                      {
                          screenShare ?
                              <ScreenShareOff onClick={() => { handleToggleVideOnScreenShare(false) }} />
                              :
                              <ScreenShare onClick={() => { handleToggleVideOnScreenShare(true) }} />
                      }
                  </button>
              }
              <CopySection roomId={roomId} />
          </div>
      );
  };
  
  export default VideoCallComp;
  
  
  import { useState } from 'react'
  import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'
  import { useSocketContext } from '../Context/SocketContext'
  
  const usePlayer = (myId, roomId, peer, stream) => {
      const socket = useSocketContext()
      const [players, setPlayers] = useState({})
      const playersCopy = cloneDeep(players);
  
  
      const nonHighlightedPlayers = playersCopy
  
      const leaveRoom = () => {
          socket.emit('user-leave', myId, roomId)
          console.log("leaving room", roomId)
          peer?.disconnect();
      }
  
      const toggleAudio = () => {
          console.log("I toggled my audio")
          setPlayers((prev) => {
              const copy = cloneDeep(prev)
              copy[myId].muted = !copy[myId].muted
              return { ...copy }
          })
          socket.emit('user-toggle-audio', myId, roomId);
      }
  
  
      const toggleVideo = () => {
          console.log("I toggled my video")
          setPlayers((prev) => {
              const copy = cloneDeep(prev);
              copy[myId].playing = !copy[myId].playing;
              return { ...copy }
          })
          socket.emit('user-toggle-video', myId, roomId)
      }
  
  
      return { players, setPlayers, nonHighlightedPlayers, toggleAudio, toggleVideo, leaveRoom }
  }
  
  export default usePlayer;
  
  import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
  
  const useMediaStream = (screenShare) => {
      const [stream, setStream] = useState(null);
  
      useEffect(() => {
          let mediaStream = null;
          let audioStream = null;
  
          const startStream = async () => {
              try {
                  // Stop any active tracks if there's an existing stream
                  if (mediaStream) {
                      mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
                  }
                  if (audioStream) {
                      audioStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
                  }
  
                  if (screenShare) {
                      mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true });
                      // Get the audio separately with additional constraints
                      audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                          audio: {
                              echoCancellation: true,
                              noiseSuppression: true,
                              autoGainControl: true
                          }
                      });
  
                      // Combine the video and audio tracks
                      mediaStream.addTrack(audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
                  } else {
                      mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
                      audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                          audio: {
                              echoCancellation: true,
                              noiseSuppression: true,
                              autoGainControl: true
                          }
                      });
                      // Combine the video and audio tracks
                      mediaStream.addTrack(audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
                  }
  
                  setStream(mediaStream);
              } catch (error) {
                  console.error("Error accessing media devices.", error);
              }
          };
  
          startStream();
  
          return () => {
              if (mediaStream) {
                  mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
              }
              if (audioStream) {
                  audioStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
              }
          };
      }, [screenShare]);
  
      return { stream };
  };
  
  export default useMediaStream;

I have tried a lot of problems but did'nt find any solution


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
